# How to dynamically add color to a gauge chart in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have a gauge chart which is showing different label for different parameters now i want to add color to the needles dynamically while loading the chart.How i can do that ?? i am posting s fiddle ,i have tried but i couldn't do that . Here is my fiddle

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var i = 0,
            j, y = this.y;

        arrTTF.forEach(function(TTF) {

            if (TTF == y) {
                j = i;
                return;
            }
            i++;
        });

        return arrLabel[j] + ": " + y + ' km/h';
    }
}
```

Above is the code someone helped me to put different label  to the needles,but i couldn't put different color runtime

[Gauge](http://jsfiddle.net/8ebw7cxf/1/)

Comment: You need to define each point as separate serie, then define color in dial object, liek here http://jsfiddle.net/8ebw7cxf/3/. You can manipulate color by [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update)

Comment: @SebastianBochan but i want a dynamic representation like when i pass 2 data with the array two needles will be showing can you modify my example which i have given ??

Comment: @SebastianBochan also i have an array of data how i can separately define their color ???

Comment: My example can be dynamic, use series.update. http://jsfiddle.net/8ebw7cxf/4/

Comment: where i should use that ???? can you plese edit my example which  i have shown

Comment: Let me know what is unclear, because I introduced dynamic chart with colors etc, which are request.

Comment: See i have used an array for the values write?? so i can not hard code the values inside that array.I have to dynamically use that array to make color also

Comment: See i have used an array for the values write?? so i can not hard code the values inside that array.I have to dynamically use that array to make color also and also when i will put 2 element inside the array then the color needles will be two and when 3 then will be 3 needles also thats it